# while processing recurring payment in paypal ,it is getting the following error

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

This recipient does not accept payments denominated in USDEC-00D98475NV4904518. Please contact the seller and ask him to update his payment receiving preferences to accept this currency.

How to solve this error.Please Advice

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's not on your end.

Seems like the recipient hasn't set "hes" account to accept the currency.

Another option, is to allow the user to choose the currency in which "hes" receives the payment.